# Shared element value for use in content items

Tags: websphere-portal

I have 2 content items inside a custom `WCM` library. (`IBM Portal`)

[image]

Both of which have an element, inherited from the `Authoring Template` they use.
The element is called `URL` and has a default value in the `Authoring Template`, of `google.com`.
If I change this value within `Test`, or within the `Authoring Template` after the 2 `Content` items are created it does not update the value used in both the `Content` items.

How could I setup such a variable/value? Which could be used in both `Content` items and always use the latest updated value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach I went with was to use a component which stores the value.

Any other components/content items etc which need this value can import the shared component.

Answer (score 0):

1) Select created content items

2) Press More button - > Apply Authoring Template

3) Select you authoring template

4) Set update existing values checkbox/ add new field, it was added (or similar)

5) Press OK

Comment: On `Portal 8.5`, there is no 'update existing values' checkbox and 'add new field' did not update the values.